# Can't trigger a search function for movie API project because useState is in a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

my problem is that I have two different components belonging to my App.js project. It's a movie database where I have a list of movies on the front page and I can search for other movies using the search bar. Since I have the search.js and movie.js ( component where i fetch api data and display), the search.js will not trigger as it cant pinpoint what needs to change. Basically my problem is that on submit, nothing changes.

search.js code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import React from 'react';

// search API used to search through database
const searchUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=d62e1adb9803081c0be5a74ca826bdbd&query="


const Search = ({  }) => {
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");


 // Search form that fetches search API and returns results
  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
  // API used to search for any movie in the database
    fetch(searchUrl + search)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setMovies(data.results);
      })
    setSearch("");}
  
  // user search input
  const searchQuery = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }


    return (
      
    <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="searchMovie">Search for a movie</label>
    <input
      className="search"
      type="search"
      placeholder="Search for a movie.."
      value={search}
      onChange={searchQuery}
      />
    </form>

    
    
    
    )
}

export default Search;
```

and my movie.js

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const images = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";

// main API used to display trending page
const apiUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=d62e1adb9803081c0be5a74ca826bdbd&page=`;


const Movie = ( {
}) => {
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data)=> {
        setMovies(data.results)
      })
  }, []);


    return (
    <section className="movieslist">
      {movies.length > 0 ? movies.map((movie) => {
        return (
        <Link to={`/movie/${movie.id}`}>
        <div className="moviePoster">
            <img src={movie.poster_path ? `${images}${movie.poster_path}` : "https://www.movienewz.com/img/films/poster-holder.jpg"} alt={movie.title} />
            <div className="movieInfo">
                <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
                <p className="voteStyle">Rating: {movie.voteAverage}</p>
                <p className="release">Release Date: {movie.release}</p>
                <p className="summary">{movie.overview}</p>
                <p className="key">{movie.id}</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        </Link>
          
        );
      }): <p class="noResults">No results found. Please try again?</p>}
        </section>


    )
}


export default Movie;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the expected behavior correctly, you're trying to update the `movies` state in `movies.js` from the `search.js`.

You are updating two different states of two different components that have no relationship with themselves and that is why nothing is happening on submit.

What you'll need is a parent component (for example home.js) that holds search and movies component as children and holds the movies state. The child components should use and update the parent's movie state.

```js
import Movies from "./movies";
import Search from "./search";

const Home = ()=>{
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
// some other code

return (
    <>
        <Search onSearh={setMovies} />
        <Movies movies={movies} onMovies={setMovies}/>
    </>);
}
```

and your movies.js and search.js should consume these props

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import React from 'react';

// search API used to search through database
const searchUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=d62e1adb9803081c0be5a74ca826bdbd&query="


const Search = ({ onSearch }) => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");


 // Search form that fetches search API and returns results
  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
  // API used to search for any movie in the database
    fetch(searchUrl + search)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        onSearch(data.results);
      })
    setSearch("");}
 

...
```

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const images = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";

// main API used to display trending page
const apiUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=d62e1adb9803081c0be5a74ca826bdbd&page=`;


const Movie = ( {movies, onMovies}) => {

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data)=> {
        onMovies(data.results)
      })
  }, []);


...
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, you put into code and words what I was trying to conjure up in my head. A home component is definitely what I was looking for so two different components can update the same state. Tried this out and it worked great! Thanks so much!